# DomNode htmlunit

Tags: java, html, string, dom

I need to create a new HtmlUnit DomNode  and insert String into this node.

Is possbile to do this?

Thanks

Comment: That's a bit vague.  Can you add an example of what you're trying to do?  Have any code you're working on that you can post?

Answer (score 1):

Probably :) because of lack of information in your question
But I assume you need to use [DomText](http://www.netlikon.de/docs/javadoc-htmlunit/htmlunit-2.0/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomText.html) - Representation of a text node in the HTML DOM

UPDATE: should be used like

```
HtmlPage page = ...; // your page
DomNode node = ...; // look for node where to insert your text
DomNode textNode = new DomText(page, "test"); 
node.appendChild(textNode );
```

You can find many examples of its using [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/xref-test/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNodeTest.html) - this is unit test for DomNode class. Start  with investigating of how they do it, and you will find the way to solve your problem too ;)

Comment: Extended my answer. Extend also your question, please, so we know what you have... Do you know where you put your text, I mean node which will be parent for that text, have you "found" it in your code etc. Example of your code would be nice to have, and we can see what's wrong, or which code should be added etc. Now it is just shot in nowhere... I feel blind :)

Comment: I need to use the function astext of DomNode class. For do this operation i nedd create a DomNode. I havnt' a HtmlPage. Thanks

Comment: Well, if you got DomNode on the page, then you definitely get a page :) you either create that page at the beginning, or load it from somewhere... How do you get DomNode? Why do you need asText function? Looks like I don't understand you. And third time on this page: extend you question, give as more as possible, and then things will be easier...

Comment: Ok Maxym Thanks for your help now i try to explain my problem. I have a String contnent a HTML page. now i need to get the contnent of this pahe like do a function astext in htmlunit. Now i think from tour response that i can do thi operation only if i have a Htmlpage creaed with webclient class right?

Comment: Well, I know that there is a lot of code, but you are going to like it :) http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/xref-test/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNodeTest.html - that's a unit test for htmlunit, you can take any method as basis, or find method called "appendChild", but as I understand you need something then just appending. Play with that code, I hope it will lead you to solution (just notice that they start from string content, transform it to the page in WebTestCase class). Probably this code is shipped with HtmlUnit library, so you can play with it in your IDE

Comment: Yes, having content you can create HtmlPage using WebClient class. You are on the right way :) And when I asked you to extend your question I meant "Edit your question", and not "Add extr info in comment to this answer". If you edit your question you become closer to help from somebody else. And you help other people to find answer to their similar questions ;)